# wordpress login.php redirectes you too many times

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

When I want to go `wp-admin` it redirects me to my homepage, when I want to go `wp-login` it takes me to homepage and at the bottom gives me the login form but without any CSS, and when I want to go `wp-login.php` it returns this error "This page isn’t working  mysite.org redirected you too many times."

My website URL starts with https, is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can go database (if your host has phpmyadmin on its cpanel) check the 'siteurl' option in the wp_options table of the database. If that option is set to an address that redirects or does not resolve, you would not be able to get into your admin section.

I have seen that sort of thing happen before when a hosting provider had a setting that redirected all requests from domain.url to www.domain.url, but the blog's 'siteurl' option was set as http://domain.url

Comment: I did it , and now it says that page can't be found and gives me a 2-5 errors about wp-login.php and wp-includes/pluggable.php and the css of my website is lost
please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but with `c9users.io` - a preview url for `c9.io` apps. It turned out the problem was in my `.htaccess` file where I was redirecting all traffic to use `https` - and that caused the problem (I think) because traffic at `c9users.io` uses `https` by default. However, uploading the `.htaccess` file to my production server works fine!
Here's the redirect rule:

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

I hope that helps :-)